# How to execute Angular 2 http call every timeInterval with Rxjs 'interval' operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this simple method in my service :

```
 notify(userID: string) {
    let _URL = this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID;
     this.datatService.set(_URL);
    return this.datatService.get()
        .flatMap((response) =>
           response.json().slice())
           .distinct();
}
```

It return a stream of object which contain informations about user's notification. i would like to execute this call every 5 second with interval operator without using setTimeout ?

When i try this :

```
 notify(userID: string) {
    let _URL = this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID;
     this.datatService.set(_URL);
    return this.datatService.get()
        **.interval(5000)**
        .flatMap((response) =>
           response.json().slice())
           .distinct();
}
```

I have an error.
Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
notify(userID: string) {
  return Observable.interval(5000)
    .map(() => this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID)
    .switchMap(url => {
      this.dataService.set(url);
      return this.dataService.get();
    })
    .map(response => ....{ <your handler> }
}
```

A few notes:
1. You must subscribe to the returned value to start the calls.
2. Your data service is statefull, this might create race condition where 2 different clients set the url and then invoke it, consider converting the get to a stateless function: `get(url)`, in which case your code will be

```
notify(userID: string) {
  return Observable.interval(5000)
    .map(() => this.baseUrl + '/notification/GetUnseen?userId=' + userID)
    .switchMap(url => this.dataService.get(url))
    .map(response => ....{ <your handler> }
}
```

Comment: I'am subscribing to the method in my component, thx for the note about the statfull function +1